# Summation of lattice points

Tags: number-theory

Let $f(x)$ be a strictly increasing function with inverse $g(x)$. Suppose $f(0)=0$, $f(a)=b$, and both $a,b >0$. 
Let $T$ be the total number of lattice points on the curve $y=f(x)$ from $O=(0,0)$ to $P=(a,b)$. Prove that $ \sum_{k=1}^{[a]} [f(k)] + \sum_{k=1}^{[b]} [g(k)] -T=[a][b] $ , where $[x]$ is the largest integer not greater than $x$.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you call lattice points are just points with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$. This question looks particularly simple when one pictures the situation on a paper. But I find it difficult to put my drawings on the internet, so I give a sketch instead.
To give a sketch of the proof, let us see what $[a][b]$ means: it is just the area of the rectangular with lengths $[a]$ and $[b]$. Now put the curve in the graph, and divide the rectangular into two parts $\mathbb A$ and $\mathbb B$, where $\mathbb A$ is the area bounded by $x$-axis and the curve, while $\mathbb B$ is the other half. Notice that here "the other half" does not imply that the two parts are completely distinct, as it means only to partition the region as $\sum [f(k)]$ and $\sum [g(k)]$. The repeated part occurs exactly whenever there is a lattice point on the curve, contributing the area by $1$. Hence, by the simple principle of combinatorics that, for two finite sets $\mathfrak A$ and $\mathfrak B$, we have $|\mathfrak A\cup \mathfrak B|=|\mathfrak A|+|\mathfrak B|-|\mathfrak A\cap \mathfrak B|$, the result follows.
[A rough idea of what is going on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI0KO.jpg)